# using if in awk in comparision with todays date

Tags: bash, awk, amazon-s3

I am looking for a command which helps me use if in awk and equates it to the current date.

A/B folder has files with different dates. I need to filter out files of the present day whenever script runs

A) Gives an output with all the dates,

```
date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`    

s3cmd ls --recursive  s3://A/B/ | grep A-B | grep .tar | awk '{  if ($1 -eq "$date" )  print $1"  "$2 "  " $3 "  " $4 }' | sort -r
```

B)Replaces $1 which contains dates with "$date" to all of them

```
date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`    

s3cmd ls --recursive  s3://A/B/ | grep A-B | grep .tar | awk '{  if ($1 = "$date" )  print $1"  "$2 "  " $3 "  " $4 }' | sort -r
```

C)Does not give any output. leaves blank

```
date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`    

s3cmd ls --recursive  s3://A/B/ | grep A-B | grep .tar | awk '{  if ($1 == "$date" )  print $1"  "$2 "  " $3 "  " $4 }' | sort -r
```

if I remove "" it does not give me any output in all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

The shell doesn't substitute variables inside double quotes. You should assign an awk variable from the shell variable. Also, the equality comparison is `==`, not `-eq` or `=`.

```
awk -v date="$date" '$1 == date { print $1"  "$2 "  " $3 "  " $4 }'
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need `awk` for that. Just use `find` and say

```
find /path/to/search/ -type f ! -newermt $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

- `$(..)` is command substitution and what it will do is expand to current date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- `! -newermt` is `find` option to look for files older than specified date
- `-type f` will only look for files

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @user3407570 You're welcome. You may choose to accept an answer that helped you the most. You can do so by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

awk is not shell. It is a completely separate tool with it's own syntax and capabilities. Therefore you should not expect to be able to use shell variables or shell syntax in an awk script. Try this:

```
s3cmd ls --recursive  s3://A/B/ |
awk -v date="$date" -v OFS="  " '/A-B/ && /.tar/ && ($1 == date) { print $1, $2, $3, $4 }' |
sort -r
```

You probably actually meant `\.tar` instead of `.tar` though and as @jaypal said, this is a job for `find`, not `ls` piped to `awk`.

Comment: hi, sorry for bothering you again, but could you please explain
    date="$date" -v OFS="  " 
I tried a lot on google could not get a clear picture of what it meant and how it works.

Thanks in advance.